# How do i display data from two tables with different amount of data on tow separate html5 tables?

Tags: php, mysql

I have been studying PHP for a few weeks now and am really loving it. I need help because all the search I have done in this regards has yielded similar result. I am building a site to track packages for a courier service. 
Basically, the staff are able to login and add a package and update the location of the package. These updates are supposed to build up as history on the package until delivery. However, with a tracking number generated, anybody can view details of the package and the current location. once a search is conducted, I have the following codes in my files to generate the information on that tracking number display.

I have three tables created as follows: usersAccounts, packages and history

```
CREATE TABLE history (
  id INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  trackingNumber BIGINT(10) NOT NULL,
  date VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL,
  time VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL,
  city VARCHAR(75) NOT NULL,
  country VARCHAR(75) NOT NULL,
  activity VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id),
UNIQUE INDEX id (id)
)
ENGINE = INNODB
```

INSERT INTO `activity` (`id`, `trackingNumber`, `date`, `time`, `city`, `country`, `activity`) VALUES
(1, 777777, '2017-06-23', '16:43:00', 'City 1', 'Country', 'Activity 1'),
(2, 777777, '2017-06-24', '13:17:09', 'City 2', 'Country', 'Activity 2'),
(3, 888888, '2017-06-23', '10:11:21', 'City 1', 'Country', 'Activity 1'),
(4, 888888, '2017-06-24', '10:43:00', 'City 2', 'Country', 'Activity 2'),
(5, 777777, '2017-06-25', '16:27:00', 'City 3', 'Country', 'Activity 3');

```
CREATE TABLE packages (
  packageID INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  sendName VARCHAR(50),
  originCity VARCHAR(70),
  originCountry VARCHAR(50),
  receiverName VARCHAR(50),
  desCity VARCHAR(255) ,
  desCountry VARCHAR(70),
  expDeliveryDate VARCHAR(10),
  status VARCHAR(255),
  trackingNumber INT(10),
PRIMARY KEY (packageID, trackingNumber),
UNIQUE INDEX trackingNumber (trackingNumber)
)
ENGINE = INNODB

CREATE TABLE userAccounts (
  id INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  username VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  password VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  status BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id),
UNIQUE INDEX username (username)
)
```

ENGINE = MYISAM

I also have two test data in the packages table: 888888 and 777777 and there is also some updates on the 88888 and 777777 in history table. My problem is that whenever a search is conducted, data for both 888888 and 777777 in the history table are displayed whereas I only wanted the details for 888888 or 777777 to be displayed as searched.

I have two queries to get the results for the two tables on the html5 table Can someone please look at my code and tell me what is wrong?

```
$query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * from packages WHERE trackingNumber LIKE '%$searchq%'");
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        $shipper = $row['sendName'];
        $originCity = $row['originCity'];
        $originCountry = $row['originCountry'];
       }
$sql =  "SELECT * from history WHERE trackingNumber LIKE '%$searchq%' ORDER 
BY id ASC";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){         
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['time']. "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['city']. "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['country']. "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['activity']. "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
```

Thank you

Comment: What errors are you getting (if any)? If no errors, do you have error reporting turned on? How is the output different from what you expect?

Comment: There are no errors and error reporting is turned. The query results from table (packages) are okay. Query result show only the value stated in the WHERE.....LIKE clause but all the rows in table(history) are shown instead of filtering.

Comment: Is there a better way to achieve this? I want to be a able to display details of a package with history like FedEx, DHL, UPS, etc.

Comment: There are few inconsistencies in your question. You mention three tables, then show the create for two of the three. Then in the code, your SQL refers to a fourth table "activity". Can you edit your question to include the schema of the activity table, and add some sample data? I'm guessing, but I think this can be done with a single query and a slight change to your php code.

Comment: Also, in your SQL code, you never execute the 2nd query.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you define the variable `$searchq` before using it in the query. For example if you are searching for data containing the number 7 you first need to declare

```php
$searchq = '7';
```

If not, `SELECT * from packages WHERE trackingNumber LIKE '%$searchq%'` will resolve to `SELECT * from packages WHERE trackingNumber LIKE '%%'`, which matches *everything*. PHP will give you a notice that something has gone wrong, but the code will still run, and you might not notice the mistake.

Comment: The variable $searchq has been declared as follows:
    if(isset($_POST['track']) && $_POST['track'] !=""){
 $searchq = $_POST['track'];
    }
The first query searches through the table returns results for exactly what was queried but the second shows everything in the second including unrelated data.

Answer (score 0):

This is basic, and you would probably want to add column headings and other formatting, but it will work for single tracking numbers and search terms that match multiple tracking numbers. It also avoids SQL injection issues by using prepared statements.

```
<?php

    $searchq = isset($_REQUEST['track']) && $_REQUEST['track'] != '' ? $_REQUEST['track'] : "";

    if($searchq != '') {

        $qstr = "";
        $qstr .= "SELECT\n";
        $qstr .= "  a.`packageID`,\n";
        $qstr .= "  a.`sendName`,\n";
        $qstr .= "  a.`originCity`,\n";
        $qstr .= "  a.`originCountry`,\n";
        $qstr .= "  b.`date`,\n";
        $qstr .= "  b.`time`,\n";
        $qstr .= "  b.`city`,\n";
        $qstr .= "  b.`country`,\n";
        $qstr .= "  b.`activity`\n";
        $qstr .= "FROM `packages` a\n";
        $qstr .= "LEFT JOIN `activity` b\n";
        $qstr .= "ON a.`trackingNumber` = b.`trackingNumber`\n";
        $qstr .= "WHERE a.`trackingNumber` = ?";

        $searchq = '%'.$searchq.'%';
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($qstr);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,'s',$searchq);
        $stmt->execute();

        $rslt = mysqli_get_result();
        $lastPackageID = "";
        echo "<table>\n";
        while($row = mysqli_getch_array($rslt)) {
            if($lastPackageID != $row['packageID']) {
                echo "<tr>\n";
                echo "  <td colspan='3'>.$row['sendName']."</td>\n";
                echo "  <td>.$row['originCity']."</td>\n";
                echo "  <td>.$row['originCountry']."</td>\n";
                echo "</tr>\n";
                $lastPackageID != $row['packageID'];
            }
            echo "<tr>\n";
            echo "  <td>.$row['date']."</td>\n";
            echo "  <td>.$row['time']."</td>\n";
            echo "  <td>.$row['city']."</td>\n";
            echo "  <td>.$row['country']."</td>\n";
            echo "  <td>.$row['activity']."</td>\n";
            echo "</tr>\n";
        }
        echo "</table>\n";

    } else {
        echo "Required parameter missing";
    }
?>
```